# Can a valid proof by contradiction contradict the opposite proposition?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Sorry if the wording in the title is a bit off, an example will better illustrate my query. Say I wanted to prove the following: $$ (x_n) \text{ and } (y_n) \text{ are both real sequences such that } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ x_n \leq y_n. \text{If } x_n \rightarrow x \text{ and } y_n \rightarrow y, \text{ then } x \leq y.$$

To prove this by contradiction we first assume the opposite proposition $ x > y $ and show that this leads to the statement $ x_n > y_n $, which contradicts one of our initial conditions (namely $ x_n \leq y_n) $.

Could an equally valid proof use the opposite proposition $ x > y $ and show that this leads to $ x = y $, which contradicts only the opposite proposition and not any initial conditions?

Comment: Yes, it works. Assume as hypothesis : $x > y$. Then derive $x=y$; now, we have a contradiction, because $x > y$ and $x=y$ cannot both be true. Finally, conclude with the negation of the assumption, i.e. with $x \le y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is yes: You may have a (very) common misconception about proof by contradiction.

To prove something by contradiction you merely derive *any* logical contradiction. In basic analysis proofs, it is often clean for your contradiction to be of the form $1 < 0$ or something concrete, *as opposed to contradicting the hypotheses*.

Answer (score 0):

As you can typically prove anything when working in an inconsistent system, *any* contradiction, whether it's (most obviously) to some condition in the formulation of the statement, to the assumption made when beginning the proof, to basic arithmetic (i.e $1>2$), ... will be the contradiction you look for (and - in most cases - can be used to "prove" any other contradiction).